# Plot circuit within TensorCircuit

Tags: quantum-circuit, tensor-networks, tensorcircuit

Given an arbitrary [TensorCircuit](https://tensorcircuit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=c.state%28%29&check_keywords=yes&area=default), is there a convient way to get a plot of the circuit?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose `c` is the circuit object, `c.tex()` will return the latex string using quantikz package, and `c.tex(standalone=True)` returns the full latex document that can be compiled.

Besides, assuming qiskit is also installed, `c.draw()` can plot the circuit via first transforming the circuit into qiskit `QuantumCircuit`. And all options for qiskit can also be given in `c.draw(**options)`

Answer (score 1):

[@Simon](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/22402/simon)'s answer is absolutely correct. I just want to add a few details.

When TensorCircuit transforms the circuit into Qiskit's `QuantumCircuit`, non-unitary operations are transformed into generic unitaries. So, the circuit plot will not be accurate. As a workaround you can add a name of each non-unitary operation, and style them with custom colors as follows:

```
import tensorcircuit as tc
c = tc.Circuit(2)
c.H(0)
c.CNOT(0,1)
c.crx(1, 0, theta=0.2)

# Add a non-unitary operation:
c.thermalrelaxation(
    0,
    t1=300,
    t2=400,
    time=1000,
    method="ByChoi",
    excitedstatepopulation=0,
    name="Thermal Relaxation" # <== 
)

# Style non-unitary operations with custom colors
style = {
    'displaycolor': {
        'Thermal Relaxation': ['#ff7675', '#000000'],
    }
}

c.draw(output = 'mpl', style = style)
```

The result will look like:

[image]